# I am trying to read the file using javascript new fileReader()

Tags: javascript, velo

I am trying to read the file using javascript `new fileReader()` function to convert the file in to binary format but is not supporting in `Wix`

please support us to resolve this issue to overcome it

```
var fr=new FileReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This helps you :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <input type="file" />
  <!-- writing JavaScript inside html -->
       
    
     <body>
    
      <input type="file" />
      <!-- writing JavaScript inside html -->
      <script>
            const filename = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    
            filename.addEventListener('change', function (){
            // Creating a FileReader object using the constructor.
    
            const filereader = new FileReader();
            // Reading a file as plain text
    
            filereader.readAsText(filename.files[0]);
            // Call this function to print the contents of the file
            // once the file has been read.
    
            filereader.onload = function {
                console.log(filereader.result);
            };
            // Print the error incase there is one
    
            filereader.onerror = function {
                console.log("Error: ", filereader.error);
            };
    },false);
      </script>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks...But new FileReader() method is not supporting in the wix that was issue i am facing

Comment: follow this, this may help you 

[turn around for FileReader][1]


  [1]: https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/solved-uploading-and-converting-files

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found a solution for you :-

try this

```
/* global FileReader */

$w.onReady(function () {
     const fileReader = new FileReader();

fetch('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e3b156_8646d72618e3420db36dba9156d0b8e7~mv2.jpg/v1/fit/w_512,h_586/o_0.jpeg')
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob));

    fileReader.onload = function () {
        // your buffer array here. But why you need it? )))
        console.log(fileReader.result);
    }
})
```

Replace URL according to your needs.
[Refer this Wix Corvid Api Overview](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-api-overview)